# What's the Russian verb for "to install (a computer application)"

Tags: перевод, глаголы, информатика

I understand *скачать* means *to download*, but what's the correct term for *install*?

(по)ставить?

Comment: Загрузить is more literal for download (load = груз). Though, скачать is more often used. Even выкачать implying files were large or many, so the very downloading process was a significant job per se. Also загрузить is quite generic. Upload - загрузить на сервер, load - загрузить в память. Boot or bootstrap - загрузить операционную систему (в память)

Comment: загрузить (на) seems to be more apt as an equivalent of UPload, a synonym of закачать (на) which belongs to a lower register, however formally загрузить is used in the sense of DOWNload

Comment: Наконец уровень (игры) загрузился. That is not from WWW, that is from disk to RAM.

Comment: "Загрузить" in the meaning of "to download" is used _much_ more rarely than "скачать". Typically it should be followed by some preposition like "загрузить на" or "загрузить себе" However, in the context of smartphones (rather than PCs) I can see "загрузить" in plain use more often.

Comment: Upload is also "залить".

Answer (score 10):

**установить/устанавливать**

**(по)ставить** can be used colloquially

Comment: The noun is установка, installation.

Answer (score 5):

**Установить** would be the most widely used form. Literally, "to set up". **Установка** means setup, installation.

Less commonly used is also the direct loanword **инсталлировать, инсталляция**. You might use this when you want to be more specific about the *type* of setup.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers provided are correct, I just want to mentioned yet another verb used casually — *заинсталлить* (or just *заинсталить* since double consonants are relatively rare in Russian), as in the following phrases:

> Нужно заинсталлить сертификат.

or

> При инсталляции Акробата есть предложение заинсталлить и принтер.

As a side note, there's even *отынсталить*, though this is used less often.

Comment: downvoter can you explain yourself? Those are real-life worlds one can easily google.

Comment: What does предложение refer to in your response? Or did you mean есть **при**ложение заинсталлить?

Comment: @CocoPop I guess that when you install Actobat you will be *prompted* to install a printer (either printer driver or add printer to Actobat, I'm not sure). With приложение the complete sentence does not make grammatical sense anymore. With предложение it is simply dense and confusing.